# impact of labels' distribution in deep learning for regression problem

Tags: keras, deep-learning, regression, conv-neural-network, signal-processing

I am trying to train a CNN model for a regression problem, after that, I categorize predicted labels into 4 classes and check some accuracy metrics. In confusion matrix accuracy of class 2,3 are around 54% and accuracy of class 1,4 are more than 90%. labels are between 0-100 and classes are 1: 0-45,2: 45-60, 3:60-70, 4:70-100. I do not know where the problem comes from Is it because of the distribution of labels in the training set and what is the solution! Regards...
I attached the plot in the following link.

[Training set target distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5etp.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to create classes that way. Giving to some classes a smaller window of values (i.e. you predict 2 for 15 values and 1 for 45 values), it is intrinsically more difficult for your model to predict class 2, and the best thing the model will learn during training will be to avoid class 2 as much as possible.

You may confirm this having a look at False Negatives for classes 2 and 3, if they are too many, it might be due to this. 
The best thing to do would be categorizing your output space in equal portions, and trusting your model will learn which classes are less frequent, without trying to force that proportion by yourself.

If you don't have good results, it means you have to improve your model in other ways, maybe using data augmentation to get a uniform distribution of training samples may help.

If this doesn't sound convincing for you, try to have a look at this paper: 
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/95-alvinn-an-autonomous-land-vehicle-in-a-neural-network.pdf

In end-to-end models for autonomous driving, neural networks have to predict classes indicating the steering angle. The distribution of these values is highly imbalanced as most of the time the car is going straight. Despite this, the best models do not discriminate against some classes to adapt to data distribution.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your reply, this categorization isn't arbitrary and each of the classes has a meaning. I am working on the signal data. Model is trained as a regression after that I divide them into 4 classes and in addition to the regression metrics, I check the accuracy metrics and confusion matrix. but class 2 and 3 are more prone to class 1 and 2.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. Given the distribution of training set that's strange. May I ask you more details on the use case? What data are you treating? What are input and output values?

Could you visualize the distribution of predicted value by your net and compare it to the training value one? At least in training, your model should be able to overfit your data, if it's not you may need to change the architecture.

Comment: (Actually, I don't use dnn as a classifier, predicted values from deep regression NN categorize into 4 classes)The data as an input is EEG signal of anesthesia and the target is depth of anesthesia, each of the classes is a level of anesthesia. Do you mean plot predicted and the target values of the training set?